# How to select DATE related to MAX value column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table `tbl` with column `date` `sales`

I perform this MySQL query:

```
SELECT DAY(date) as DAY, count(sales) as sales_count
FROM tbl
```

I get this result:

```
DAY      sales_count
1        224
2        361
3        155
4        281
.......
30       416
31       332
```

Now, I find the `DAY` in `WEEK` when the sales were `MAX` by doing this:

```
SELECT DAY(date) as DAY, WEEK(date) as WEEK, max(count(sales)) as MAX_SALES, 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY WEEK(date)
```

and I get this:

```
DAY    WEEK      MAX_SALES
1      1         324
8      2         461
15     3         255
22     4         481
.......
```

The `WEEK` and `MAX_SALES` are correct but the `DAY` value seems to be the first `DAY` of the `WEEK` and not the `DAY` of the `MAX_SALES` occurred. I can confirm it is because we have `GROUP BY WEEK` and that is how `DAY` is getting the value related to `WEEK`. We cannot group by `MAX()`

How do I have the `DAY` value reflect the `MAX_SALES` date in the `WEEK`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use subquery.

```
SELECT weekDay,
       DAY,
       MAX(sales_count)
FROM (
    SELECT DAY(date) as DAY, 
           Week(date) as weekDay
           count(sales) as sales_count
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY 
        DAY(date),
        Week(date)      
) t1
group by 
       weekDay,
       DAY
```

Comment: I still get all the days, not just MAX(sales_count) day